# How do you execute different C++ files within the same solution in microsoft visual studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I am trying to set up a project, I chose a console application and made it empty, so I add multiple files that just print out some text. I then compile and execute one file and it runs fine, but when I go to run a different one it runs the one that I just ran. I really don't know how to fix this so if you guys could help me that would be great.

Comment: How are you "compiling and executing one file"?

Comment: A program can be made up of many code files, but when you run it you don't just execute one of them. All of them are built into the program. Execution starts in the one-and-only main function and then proceeds as per whatever other functions you call within that.

Comment: when you say "multiple files that just print out some text" are you talking about separate .cpp files each with a `main` function that are independent of each other?

Answer (score 1):

Each console application can only have one `main` function that starts when the application is run. However, you can have multiple console applications per Visual Studio solution. If you right-click on a console application in the Solution Explorer you can click **Set as StartUp Project** so that it starts when you "run" your solution.